# Page is not refereshing on file change in React with Webpack & Express configuration

Tags: reactjs, express, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have created an react application from scratch with the help of webpack and express server. However, everthing is working fine except page is not reloading whenever i do some changes in my react component. Can you please tell me what could be issue with my webpack config or express or package.json file ?

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require("path");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// static server

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "dist")));

// route

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname, "/dist/index.html");
});

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
  const webpack = require("webpack");
  const webpackConfig = require("./webpack.config");
  const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);

  app.use(require("webpack-dev-middleware")(compiler));

  app.use(
    require("webpack-hot-middleware")(compiler, {
      noInfo: true,
      publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
    })
  );
}

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("listening at localhost:3000");
});
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: {
    app: "./src/hello.jsx",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.(js|jsx)$/, use: ["babel-loader"] },
      { test: /\.(css)$/, use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"] },
      { test: /\.(jpg|png|jpeg)$/, use: ["file-loader"] },
      { test: /\.(html)$/, use: ["html-loader"] },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/hello.html",
      filename: "index.html",
      chunks: ["app"],
    }),
  ],
  output: {
    filename: "[name].bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "webpack-react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "react and webpack",
  "main": "server.js",
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "webpack"
  ],
  "author": "james",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.0",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.17.10",
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.2",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.17.12",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.72.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.25.1"
  }
}
```

hello.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./hello.css";

const Hello = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Hello React</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept();
}

ReactDOM.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: In `./src/hello.jsx` try adding the line `if(module.hot) module.hot.accept();` at the bottom of the file.

Comment: @code Not working after adding as you said. Also I have added my hello.jsx file

Comment: I believe I found the issue. [`webpack-hot-middleware`](https://npmjs.com/package/webpack-hot-middleware) needs to be used after registering [`webpack-dev-middleware`](https://npmjs.com/package/webpack-dev-middleware), which connects the Webpack compiler with Express. Run `npm i webpack-dev-middleware`, then change your first Webpack middleware from the hot middleware to the Webpack dev middleware (see the docs on the npm page). In other words, you're registering the hot middleware twice without setting up the required dev middleware; I'm not sure why there wasn't a warning.

Comment: Also, shouldn't it be `if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production")`? You're only running the Webpack thing on production mode (**you're not even running it unless in prod**), so you have a total of two (three, but one already fixed) fatal problems, which is why the previous code didn't throw. Whew, were you really tired when you wrote that code?

Comment: @code I changed whatever u said but getting this error after successfull compiled Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'D:\webpack-react\dist\index.html'. Also I have updated server.js file

Comment: Now you changed both of your webpack hot middleware to two webpack dev middleware! You want one webpack dev middleware, *and then* one webpack hot middleware.

Comment: Also, why do you have config for the webpack dev server? Please remove that; you're using a custom server, not webpack's dev server.

Comment: Actually I did the same thing after few time, I have one webpack dev middleware & webpack hot middleware. After that I have to referesh my app then only showing latest changes. Browser not reloading whenever I change the code. Also I didn't use webpack dev server. Can you please tell us where I have use ?

Comment: Can you update `server.js` with your new code? Okay, so in `webpack.config.js`, in the last property you have `devServer`. It's not supposed to be there, is it?

Comment: I have updated both server and webpack config file

Comment: Still not working? Make sure to save all your files and restart the server!

Comment: I am not saying that it is not working it's just browser is not reloading whenever i make change in hello.jsx file. It is correct way to write about hot reloading in hello.jsx file

Comment: Hmm... that's strange. You sure you saved all your files and restarted the server and reloaded the page and tried editing your React again and seeing the output, right? I once made a working template thing with Express and working HMR, you might want to compare it with your current code: https://github.com/codingjlu/express-react-template

Comment: Ah, try changing the entry from `entry: { app: "./src/hello.jsx" }` to `entry: { app: ["webpack-hot-middleware/client", "./src/hello.jsx"] }`

Comment: Yeah it is wroking thanks man for your support. I just wanted to learn these stuff. Because I got bored creating react app with traditional way. One minor isseu face in route on my sever.js. I was using this way to server html file app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "dist", "/index.html"));
}); but I was getting no such file exist then i change to this app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname, "/dist/index.html");
});

Comment: What did you do for it to work? I'm so glad you figured it out. Happy coding!! :) (I hope you learned several things along the way; there were like 4 or 5 problems that had to be fixed.)

Comment: @code I have modify my prev comment. Can you please look into that why it's happening ?

Comment: You might want to log the different attempts. My guess is the `/` in `"/index.html"` in `path.join`.

Comment: @code it's not working with that approach and I use this way app.get("/", (req, res) => { res.sendFile(__dirname, "/dist/index.html"); }), i don't see my bundle.js, img & html inside dist folder. However, everything is working fine. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Sorry, no. Glad you got it fixed though!